# How X509 Certificate renewal does not impact the code?

Tags: c#

What attribute should I use to load the certificate from cert store in code so that no
 change is required when the certificate is renewed?

Answer (score 4):

The `Subject` (distinguished name) is what's generally used for this in any libraries that use certificates (WCF, WSE and the like).  You should be safe with that.

Comment: Note that the search method is typically configurable, otherwise it wouldn't be much of a library - but distinguished name is the default option.

Comment: I am already running into multiple cert with same subject exception while trying to use subject name to load the cert(i am assuming there is no property like distinguished name, by distinguished you meant unique subject? right?).
Yes all these propertty is configurable. But I was looking for a solution where i donot even have to touch any config property while certficate expierd & renewed. Idea is to find a single property like Thumbprint or Sr Number or subject which does not change with the renewal of cert.

Comment: @Niel: You should not have multiple certificates with the same subject.  That points to an error in your overall system design.  If for some reason you do have this, then I would choose the most recent one to use.  Serial number and thumbprint will change when the cert is renewed, that's fundamental to X.509.  Subject (DN) is the only property I know of that will stay the same.